# When to use GBaseInitFunc

Tags: c, glib

So I was reading glib manual [Instantiable classed types: objects: GObject Reference Manual](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/unstable/gtype-instantiable-classed.html). I know that when I am creating my own class I should use GClassInitFunc to handle class initialization. Question is, when do I need to use GBaseInitFunc?

Answer (score 2):

Not to be flip, but I think the answer is "extremely rarely." I've never had to use it.

This is a really good question though. I was curious so I did a [code search](https://github.com/search?q=org%3AGNOME+GBaseInitFunc&type=Code). It looks like the majority of occurrences of `GBaseInitFunc` are just casting a null pointer to the correct function pointer type. Some others I don't understand what they are doing. [Here](https://github.com/GNOME/libdmapsharing/blob/5dd534e957020b5d3a64b4ea08d6f1ce84a7ce58/libdmapsharing/dmap-record-factory.c#L46)'s one that is used to keep track of how many classes are initialized from that base class (though the info doesn't seem to be used.)

Comment: It that true that GClassInitFunc wont be called when your class is inherited but GBaseInitFunc will be called when inherited?

Comment: No idea, sorry. Why not write a small program to test it?

Comment: Good idea :D Gonna do this tomorrow